# How to make ng-repeat in angular js with json

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am having trouble with making a list with json data. I have some json data like this

```
[
  {
    "date time":"2017-05-15 12:45:24",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-15 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-15 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-16 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-16 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-18 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-19 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-19 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-19 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 },
 {
    "date time":"2017-05-19 12:45:32",
    "latitude":"-7.9786395",
    "longitude":"112.5617418"
 }
]
```

I want to make list from json per date but if I use this json it want make list per data not per date. or maybe my code in php is wrong.

**php code**

```
$sqlcode = $con->query("select `date time`, `latitude`, `longitude` from data WHERE `imei`='$w12' AND `latitude` < '212' AND `date time` BETWEEN '$w22-01 00:00:00' AND '$w22-31 23:59:59'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$jsonObj = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlcode)) {
    $jsonObj[] = $result;
}
$final_res = json_encode($jsonObj);
echo $final_res;
```

I want to make list like this http://plnkr.co/edit/e41n9vAMMLf0WWIUQ8HO?p=preview.

Comment: what does you mean of `perdata not per date`?

Comment: `date time` is wrong, you can't set object params with space between two word, because you can't select it

Comment: i mean make list data from date, in my json in one date there more than one data. if i use my json data will be make list from data not from date. i must fix my php code, right ?

Comment: make "date time" as date_time

Comment: "date time" is from database ectually is not problem if date time or date_time

Comment: Hi @RizkaNugroho, Is your requirement is to group the lat-long details based on the date?? like this ?? `[
  {
    "date time": "2017-05-19 12:45:32",
    "lat_long_1": [
      {
        "latitude": "-7.9786395",
        "longitude": "112.5617418"
      }
    ],
    "lat_long_2": [],
    "lat_long_3": []
  }
]`

Comment: @AlexisToby yes right, i want group lat-lng by date

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay. I generated the required format of JSON using AngularJS and UnderscoreJS, hence I am not familiar with PHP. Please refer the JSBin in the link, you will get the formatted JSON. Beautify it in online and you can see the grouped data. Please use the similar loops in your code and you can attain it. I hope it will help. I included the underscore.js inline, it's not loading online in JSBin. Thank you.

[JSBin Link](https://jsbin.com/nitovawosu/edit?html,js,output)

Embeded
`<a class="jsbin-embed" href="https://jsbin.com/vipicus/embed?html,js,output">JS Bin on jsbin.com</a><script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.min.js?4.0.4"></script>`

Comment: it good but it's not what i want, but thanks for give me some tutorial

Comment: Sorry, I made that structure based on your last comment in the quest. Sorry for the trouble.